# HIbernate One-to-One Mapping Classes Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I am new to hibernate i am doing one to one mapping,
I have a doubt,

```
`     
        Stock stock = new Stock();

        stock.setStockCode("4715");
        stock.setStockName("GENM"); 

        StockDetail stockDetail = new StockDetail();
        stockDetail.setCompName("GENTING Malaysia");
        stockDetail.setCompDesc("Best resort in the world");
        stockDetail.setRemark("Nothing Special");
        stockDetail.setListedDate(new Date());

        stock.setStockDetail(stockDetail);
        /* why below line */
        stockDetail.setStock(stock);

        session.save(stock);`
```

mydoubt is that why we want to insert the Stock object in StockDetail Object???
since we are already inserting StockDetail in Stock Object.

Comment: You might be doing two way mapping i.e

Comment: For your reference, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional --8.2. Unidirectional associations & 8.4. Bidirectional associations

Comment: There is containment relationship between Stock and StockDetail classes. You are embedding Stock object in Stockdetail. You have the table structure and the code. Else you can merge both classes into one class depending on your application requirement.

Comment: I guess your snippet is from great Mk Yong tutorial. You have to show your classes mapping so we can understand which is source side and which is inverse side.

Comment: thnx @AdityaEkbote for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Saving `stock` object we required

```
       Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockCode("4715");
        stock.setStockName("GENM");
```

But for saving `stock` along with `StockDetail` you need to set fields for both and to get Id of saved `stock`( to save with `StockDetail` as we require to maintain foreign key relationship)

it requires the `StockDetail.getStock().getId()`

statement `stock.setStockDetail(stockDetail);`  setting details of `stock` for `StockDetail` object.
Included the saved and generated Id for `stock` from database.